# Images not watched

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to make an image gallery. I have one controller with two functions and every function load one view. When I call index I can watch images but when I call the other one (tg) I can't watch them.

Images are in a folder named imagenes and its path is example.com/codeigniter.

The controller:

```
class Galeria extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() 
{
    $this->load->view('vgaleria');
}

public function tg() 
 {
    $this->load->view('tgaleria');
 }
 }
```

The default controller is this one.

The view that I can't watch images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Galería de imágenes</title>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>javascript/funciones.js"   
       language="javascript" input="type/text"> 
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>


     <div id="imgs">
   <img src="imagenes/imagen1.jpg" id="eimg">
     </div>

    <input type="button" id="bant" onclick="imginter('arrancar')" 
      value="Arrancar">     
    </button>
    <input type="button" id="bsig" onclick="imgparar()" value="Parar"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I watch images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>imagenes/imagen1.jpg" id="eimg">
```

Would also depend if you have removed your `index.php` from the url using `.htaccess`. Otherwise use `site_url()`.

Comment: I tried it using base_url() and it didn't work. But it works now. Thanks.